# Can't understand matrix based derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\beta(k,d)=(X'X+kI)^{-1}(X'y+kdB_L)$
$=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}(X'y+kdB_L)$
$=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}(B_L+kd(X'X)^{-1}B_L)$
$=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}(B_L- dB_L)+dB_L$

$B_L=(X'X)^{-1}Xy$
X=n*p observed matrix
y=n*1 responses
I=identity matrix  n*n
k is a constant
d is a constant

The points that confuse me are:

1.) How does $(X'X+kI)^{-1}=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}$

2.) How do you get from line 3 to the final result shown in line 4?

Baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point $1)$ (factor out $X'X$ within the matrix inverse operation) 
$$(X'X+kI)^{-1}=(\color{blue}{(X'X)}\color{red}{[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]})^{-1}=\color{red}{[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}}\color{blue}{(X'X)^{-1}}$$

Point $2)$ (going from line $3$ to $4$) - simplify right matrix of multiplication as follows:-
$$[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}\color{green}{(B_L+kd(X'X)^{-1}B_L)}\\=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}\color{green}{((1-d)I+dI+kd(X'X)^{-1})B_L}\\=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}(\color{red}{(1-d)I}+\color{blue}{d[I+k(X'X)^{-1}])B_L}\\=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}\color{red}{[(1-d)I]B_L}+\color{blue}{dB_L}\\=[I+k(X'X)^{-1}]^{-1}(B_L-dB_L)+dB_L$$

Comment: Sorry Point 1 was easier than I thought.

Comment: No need to apologise. Sometimes we think things are more complicated than they are, and vice versa.